# Regex match line starting with whitespace and first character is non-digit

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am trying to create a regex that will only match lines that start with whitespace, then have 1-4 non-digits as the first characters, and then at least one or more spaces after the digits. The purpose of this regex is to use it in the "Find and Replace" option of Notepad++ to remove any lines that do not start with space(s) and then have a number as the first character in the line.

What I have now is allowing me to match the lines that start with whitespace and are followed with a group of digits and another space. However, these are the lines I want to keep. How can I modify the following regex so that it will match everything else other than these lines?

```
/^([\s]+\d[\s]|[\s]+\d\d[\s]|[\s]+\d\d\d[\s])/gm
```

Here's an example of the data we're using the regex on. The regex should only match the lines that DO NOT start with 1, 2, 49, 50, 99 and 100. Note that the lines that start with "40th" and "5/23/2017" should match.

```
                                                                      Page 1
          40th Marathon and 25th Marathon Relay
5/23/2017      USATF Certified Marathon (#RE98723UB)      Downtown/City, ST
Timing: Race Services    See our Calendar of Events at www.website.com
             Results questions: http://www.website.com/fixresults
=====================================================================================
                 **** FINAL RESULTS IN NETTIME ORDER ****
Place Div/Tot  Div   Halfway 22miles Guntime  Nettime Pace  Name   
===== ======== ===== ======= ======= =======  ======= ===== =======
    1   1/153  M0139 1:15:08 2:05:50 2:29:20   2:29:20  5:42 Eric
    2   2/153  M0139 1:15:07 2:06:29 2:29:56*  2:29:56  5:44 Bryan
Record 2:17:35 by Randy in 1986
   49   8/77   M4049 1:36:48 2:54:03 3:37:02   3:36:59  8:17 Joshua
   50  28/153  M0139 1:49:45 3:03:56 3:37:38#  3:37:22  8:18 Brian
# Under USATF OPEN guideline
   99   1/16   M6069 1:56:30 3:15:24 3:51:06   3:50:46  8:49 Paul
  100   3/35   F5059 1:50:06 3:11:37 3:51:03   3:50:47  8:49 Ashley
  101   4/35   F5059 1:55:26 3:16:37 3:56:03   3:55:57  9:14 Joan
* Under USATF Age-Group guideline
% For an Explanation of AgeGraded Percentages, See Here: http://www.website.com/agegrading
```

So if we used the regex in Notepad++ to find the matching strings/lines and replace (delete) them, the desired end result would be as follows (in other words, the following lines would NOT match the regex):

```
    1   1/153  M0139 1:15:08 2:05:50 2:29:20   2:29:20  5:42 Eric
    2   2/153  M0139 1:15:07 2:06:29 2:29:56*  2:29:56  5:44 Bryan
   49   8/77   M4049 1:36:48 2:54:03 3:37:02   3:36:59  8:17 Joshua
   50  28/153  M0139 1:49:45 3:03:56 3:37:38#  3:37:22  8:18 Brian
   99   1/16   M6069 1:56:30 3:15:24 3:51:06   3:50:46  8:49 Paul
  100   3/35   F5059 1:50:06 3:11:37 3:51:03   3:50:47  8:49 Ashley
  101   4/35   F5059 1:55:26 3:16:37 3:56:03   3:55:57  9:14 Joan
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/OQeJBs/2)

```
^(?! +\d+ ).*\n*
```

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `(?! +\d+ )` Negative lookahead ensuring what follows is not one or more spaces, then one or more digits, then a space
- `.*` Match any character (except `\n`) any number of times
- `\n*` Matches any number of newline characters

Result:

```
    1   1/153  M0139 1:15:08 2:05:50 2:29:20   2:29:20  5:42 Eric
    2   2/153  M0139 1:15:07 2:06:29 2:29:56*  2:29:56  5:44 Bryan
   49   8/77   M4049 1:36:48 2:54:03 3:37:02   3:36:59  8:17 Joshua
   50  28/153  M0139 1:49:45 3:03:56 3:37:38#  3:37:22  8:18 Brian
   99   1/16   M6069 1:56:30 3:15:24 3:51:06   3:50:46  8:49 Paul
  100   3/35   F5059 1:50:06 3:11:37 3:51:03   3:50:47  8:49 Ashley
  101   4/35   F5059 1:55:26 3:16:37 3:56:03   3:55:57  9:14 Joan
```

Comment: thank you! Is there a way to exclude the first line of the string/file from being included in the regex? I know I could manually select the remaining lines, but if there's a way to do this within the regex that'd save some extra work.

Comment: @irishrunner16 what about [`(?!\A)^(?! +\d+ ).*\n*`](https://regex101.com/r/OQeJBs/3)?

Comment: Works great @ctwheels One last question: Any way to also exclude only the first occurrence a line that starts with "Place"? I know `(?!\A)^(?! +\d+ |.*Place).*\n*` would match all lines that start with Place, but if more than one line starts with one or more spaces, then "Price", we only want to exclude the first instance.

Comment: @irishrunner16 I can't think of a way to do that without variable width lookbehinds.

Answer (score 0):

If this is to use in the Find/Replace dialog then you can use a cunning trick...

`^(pattern_I_want_to_keep)$|^.*$`

And replace it with

`\1`

Anything that doesn't match what you want to keep will be removed, although it will leave a blank line. They can be removed with a plugin or another regex.

This is simpler to read than concocting a match for what you don't want to keep, or using a negative lookahead.

Comment: BTW, my point about using this in Find/Replace is because I feel this reflects the original purpose clearly and is more easily managed "by hand". If I was coding this solution then I would use another approach.